# Magento Using https:// for all links in source

Tags: html, .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite

So today I was trying to install a fresh instance of Magento v1.7.0 on my vps which is running nginx. Once I uploaded the clean install to public_html I unzipped it and entered my ip to run the install i.e. xx.x.xxx.xxx:8086. Initially I got a "SSL connection error" in chrome, so I then tried http://xx.x.xxx.xxx:8086 this then worked and redirected me to the magento install page but I noticed the style was broken so I went to view the source and found that every link had https:// before it. Example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://xx.x.xxx.xxx:8086/skin/install/default/default/css/reset.css" type="text/css"   media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://xx.x.xxx.xxx:8086/skin/install/default/default/css/boxes.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://xx.x.xxx.xxx:8086/skin/install/default/default/css/clears.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

I then had a look around the default .htaccess file to see if there where any rewrites but didn't notice any.

Default .htaccess file with v1.7.0:

http://pastebin.com/natxdEUW

Any ideas what could be causing this issue?

Cheers.

Comment: htaccess doesn't modify your html, so you'll have to look somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

In your admin dashboard look under System > Configuration in the left menu choose GENERAL > WEB there you can see the Secure and Unsecure tabs and check/change this settings.

Comment: cheers for the feedback but unfortunately this issue is occurring before i have even installed magento so I cant even access the admin section.